# Cookie with value separated by comma

Tags: c#, post, cookies, webclient, cookiecontainer

I have a problem with getting and sending this cookie header. To be more specific - with that MenuData cookie.

I'm sending GET request and with response i get this one particular cookie which I need to send back in next POST request. 
The problem is that i get it in two parts(in cookiecontainer) and i have no idea how to Encode/Decode it to send it properly.

Here's the cookie header of POST i'm trying to send.
(//// - parts i need to put together)

```
Cookie:

//// MenuData={'Type':null;

ASP.NET_SessionId=oe5qzthlb51ri5nzxddadzzo;
.LoginISerwis=2880E262ECC48BD7D12443EDC97D9641E85401A345B629C2002AC89F22CEBD201700417EB0D499C6E8F10816AC1F457FF7CBD671C83509CEF405236C91D6CDD81543BF1EC507319EDD587E6FFDEBA80DFAD30D769DF6F70C942ABBCB383A0C0A0BF127F40FB4C04F25A6F68469EFAF51503EF10DCFF2F51A9B31040575B14962; 

CustomerLogin=ID=xxxx&Login=xxxxx&RememberLogin=True;


//// 'Id':null}=
```

I need an advices how I can handle this kind of cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `CookieContainer` is known to have problems with parsing cookies with **commas** in them. My advice is to manually read the cookie header at this particular step and pass the cookie along to your next request.